# Cookies are not setting with setcookie();

Tags: php, json, ajax, cookies

I've a server where I test everything before setting it in my main server. The issue appears when i'm setting a cookie with setcookie();

I'm using a cookie to set a session with ajax, the code is this:

```
require '../init.php';
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$newhash = createHash();

//LOGIN STUFF
if(strtolower($user) == strtolower($userA['user']))
{
    if($pass == $userA['pass'])
    {
        $expiration = ( time() + ( 24 * 60 * 60 * 365) );
        setcookie('session', $newhash, $expiration, '/');
        $userAdd = MYSQL_::Bits("INSERT INTO users_sessions (hash,userid) VALUES ('$newhash','$userAID')");
        //LOGIN STUFF
    }
    else
    {
        $datos = array('response' => 'fail','reason' => 'pass');
    }
}
else
{
    $datos = array('response' => 'fail','reason' => 'user');
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($datos, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

This code works perfectly on localhost, but when I put it in my main host it doesn't. I've been reading all this related posts on stackoverflow and no one has the solution, it says that there can't be nothing before the cookie but it'd be impossible to set the cookie with nothing before it. I wish someone had the answer :-(

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is causing an issue, but have you tried any other name than `session`? I have a feeling this is causing a conflict with session cookies.

Comment: There can be no html output before the `setCookie()` because the cookie is part of the headers and the headers must be sent before the html output.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - but how then it works for him on localhost?

Comment: @Darius.V: I'm responding to his remark: "...  it says that there can't be nothing before the cookie but it'd be impossible to set the cookie with nothing before it.". The clarification is that there can be no html output, not even a single space, but there can be PHP code.

Comment: What is `createHash();`? As far as I can see it's undefined. Do you have errors on?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware There is no HTML output before setting the cookie, all there's in the init.php file is PHP code and as you can see in the script there's no HTML output

Comment: @Andreas it's a function defined on init.php I've tested it and works perfectly. I thought the same as you and tried with `setcookie('test', 'test1', 1513974410, '/');` and the same happens

Comment: @Darius sometimes local PHP interpreters fix small errors that "live" interpreters don't.

Comment: We need to see init to then

Comment: @Andreas: I agree. ;-)

Comment: What does browser console say? `$userA['user']` is also undefined, and pass to. You need to edit your post and add it all or we won't be able to help you

Comment: I think enabling all error reporting in PHP, or looking in the error log, might also be helpful.

Comment: @Andreas $userA['user'] and the other variables are defined between LOGIN STUFF and believe me they output everything perfectly

Comment: @KIKOSoftware the last error is this `[28-Nov-2017 17:53:04 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$artID' (T_VARIABLE) in /home/quepeli1/public_html/ajax/getepisodes.php on line 6` but its not related to the archive which is named `order.php`

Comment: Not sure if it's a copy paste "error" but you have indented the php tag in one of the files. That is interpreted as HTML output.

Comment: One way to debug this is to move the setcookie to just below the PHP tag in the code you have posted in question with just "fake values". If that works you have output somewhere. Then you can move the setcookie further down and see when it stops working. That's the spot with output.

Comment: @Andreas I've tried it before and stops working when i put it below require init.php That's my problem, don't understand why it stops work right there :S

Comment: Because of output. Place it inside init and see where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have output somewhere in init.php or any files init includes.
The output can be direct, as in a echo.
Or a space before the PHP tag or I think even an error/notice created by PHP.
As I wrote in comments find out where your output is, we can't help you with that.

You can as mentioned move then setcookie around in your code and see where it works and where it doesn't work.
When it stops working you have found the line that creates an output.

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem happened because there was a space at the beginning of the document before `<?php` y really feel so dumb haha